# Debugging File only debugs whole project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a maven web application in Netbeans. In my project I have a class with a main method, where I mostly test some stuff on the go and I was always able to only debug this main class. 
But when I want to debug the class now, it runs the whole project. I click on Debug > Debug File.
Is there a config or something, that I have to change? Google couldn't help me.

main class:

```
public class MyMain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ..my Code here  

     }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your class to your question? Looks like you cannot run your class (no main method). I recommend to write a unit test and check correctness by unit testing: http://www.yegor256.com/2016/02/09/are-you-still-debugging.html

Comment: @XupyprMV added my main class. I will be writing unit tests in future but I still would like to know why I can't debug my main class.